# Infinispan cache is not getting evicted in Azure Kubernates cluster nodes with EmbeddedCacheManager

Tags: spring-boot, azure, kubernetes, infinispan

I'm new to configuring Infinispan cache in Spring Boot. I've set up two Spring Boot applications, node 1 and node 2. I'm using Infinispan cluster cache and have created a bean using EmbeddedCacheManager with global configurations. In my setup, I populate the cache in node 2 and attempt to evict it in node 1, which works fine locally. However, when I deploy my apps to an Azure Kubernetes environment with two pods, app1 and app2, I encounter an issue where I can't evict the cache from app1 that was populated in app2.

```
ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    confBuilder.expiration().lifespan(8, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    confBuilder.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC);
    confBuilder.clustering().stateTransfer().awaitInitialTransfer(false);
    confBuilder.transaction().transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
    confBuilder.build()
```

I have tried locally where I can evict cache in one node from other node. Please help me with any suggestion or configuration changes.
I'm wondering if I should switch to using RemoteCacheManager, or if there might be something wrong with my cache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are invoking the `Cache.evict()` method. The Eviction is local to a cache and node. From [evict() javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/14.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/Cache.html#evict(K)):

> Note that the entry is not removed from any configured cache stores or any other caches in the cluster (if used in a clustered mode).